# Can any one tell what's wrong with the following script in disabling the list of dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I used [Keith-Wood](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) calendar for that i added some script as follows

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$function(){
var holidays = ['12-2-2010', '12-7-2010', '12-10-2010', '12-18-2010'];

$('#txtDateofBirth').datepick({onDate: function(date) {
   for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
       if (date.toString('MM-dd-yyyy')==holidays[i]) {
           return {selectable: false, dateClass: 'holiday'};
       }
   }
   return $.datepick.noWeekends(date);
}});
    </script>
```

I am also having this too to disable `weekends`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
$('#txtDateofBirth').datepick({
onDate: $.datepick.noWeekends, showTrigger: '#Img1'
});
});

    </script>
```

But i am unable to disable the dates as per in the list can any one tell what's wrong i am doing

My design is as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateofBirth" runat="server" Style="left: 398px; position: absolute;
top: 131px" />
 <div style="display: none;">
 <img id="Img1" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger" style="left: 568px;
 position: absolute; top: 136px" />
  &nbsp;
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

holidays[i] is a string, you cant use a getTime() on it. 
So rather do

```
if (date.toString('MM-dd-yyyy')==holidays[i])
```

Comment: Yes you need to change your dates to 2 digits ie like 12-2-2010 to 12-02-2010, and i dont see the change i told you in your code

Comment: So as per you saying there is no need to write like this `'12-2-2010'`

Comment: But still i am not getting my result if you have done this can you post the script as per my requirement

Comment: Can you add this code, alert(date.toString('MM-dd-yyyy')); outside the for loop and tell me what it is alerting

Comment: I didn't get any alert if i write that